# mass copy files of specific extensions to folder

Tags: batch

I recently recovered a drive that was corrupted. it has a ton of extra files I do not need but I do need to copy files by extension over to the new location, eg: .jpg .png .mov .mp4 .wav .pdf .doc ext, ther are held in multiple sub directories along with a lot of crap files. like .java and .txts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `rsync -avm --include='*.ext' -f 'hide,! */' "dir" "dir"`, I completed the task and made a .sh script duplicating the method for the other extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal

```
cd /media/drew/recovered-drive/home/drew
cp -r *.jpg /home/drew/Pictures
cp -r *.mov /home/drew/Videos
etc...
```

Does this help?

Comment: does not work get error "cp: cannot stat '*.jpg' No suhc file or directory"

Comment: sudo does not change the outcome... it seems that it should work though, odd

Comment: Oh... those file paths might not actually exist. I was just giving examples of what you could do. While you are typing that in, try tab competition. Or see this article for help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal

Answer (score 0):

Lazy man's way is to delete the junk files first.

```
find . -name "*.java" -type f|xargs rm -f
find . -name "*.txt" -type f|xargs rm -f
```